# How can I save a personal bookmark file?

Tags: bookmarks, config

I work on doom-emacs and keep personal configuration in `.doom.d`, thus leave the gene config `.emacs.d`.

Today, I re-installed doom.emacs to `.emacs.d`, but find all my bookmarks disappeared when launch in.

How can I save a personal bookmarks file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you clobber your original `~/.emacs.d/` directory?  You may have lost all manner of things if you've done that.

Assuming you backed it up first, just grab the `~/.emacs.d/bookmarks` file from your backup.

If there's no such file, check <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `bookmark-default-file` to see what it was actually called.